# Does a short question really deserve downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I put this question, to someone knowledged in `python` and `google-api` the info given I think is enough to form an answer, it was a really short question indeed, but had an answer, does it really deserve the down-voting?

Question in cause:
[How can I get the author and title by knowing the ISBN using Google Book API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26360699/1577343)

Comment: BTW: It also has 3 close-votes. (Not mine)

Comment: It has been closed as "too broad" (mine included). I left a comment on the post explaining my reasoning.

Comment: Also, do you think that [the first revision on the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26360917/revisions) is at all aproprate? That should have been downvoted _on sight_.

Comment: If you added a route that you'd tried in your question and narrowed down what exactly you're trying to achieve, this would be less broad and could possibly be reopened. Right now, it reads as "How do I quickly call an API with this information using [language]?" that is commonly received as a "Give me the codez" question

Comment: ok, should I delete it ?

Comment: improve it, don't delete it :)

Comment: @CarrieKendall I edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a short question really deserve downvotes?

A question's length is not a direct factor to its quality. There are many questions that are [very short](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/234371/306635/) and [very long](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/234371/306637/) that are heavily upvoted. Another post to read about this is [When is it appropriate to ask a long question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252230/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-a-long-question)

However, it is true that (like in your example) [short questions are often closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/234378/306648/ratio-of-close-questions-for-short-questions), in what seems to be a 3:1 ratio (3 open for every 1 closed).

---

Now, to address your individual example:

That question is *way* too broad. I'll repeat what I said in the comments on the post:

> It's great that you self-answered your own question, and the answer is of good quality, but you need to make sure that the question can still be answerable by other people. Your post has been closed as "too broad" because there are just too many methods to solve the problem, and you have not shown us any of your attempts.

We really expect people to make an attempt to solve the problem. The question is too open ended to not be a "list question". The answer provided by the OP is only *one of thousands* of answers that could be given, which does not fit the "canonical post" model we strive for.